# Issue with delayed_job gem 2.0.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Hi I am getting following error while executing my controller.

```
uninitialized constant Delayed
```

I have the following code in my controller.

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(DelayedWorker.new({:model=>object.class.to_s, :object_id=>object.id,:meth=>:create_suggestion}))
```

`delayed_worker.rb` contains the following code.

```
class DelayedWorker < Struct.new(:options)

  def perform

    if obj=Object.const_get(options[:model]).find(options[:object_id])

      if (options[:para] ? obj.send(options[:meth],options[:para].first) : obj.send(options[:meth]))
        puts "Successfull"
      else
        puts "Failed"
      end
    end    
  end
end
```

I am using rails 2.3.5 version rails. I have already run:

```
$ script/generate delayed_job
$ rake db:migrate
```

I also ran `rake jobs:work` task. It runs successfully,
but while executing my controller I am getting an uninitialized constant related error.

Any one could you please help me on this.

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate require statement in your controller?

Comment: No i didn't add require statement in controller. Shall I need to add require statement?
If require please let me know the statement.

Comment: I have also upgraded my project into rails 3.2.1. for this the delayed_job is working fine.I am getting this error only for rails 2.3.5 and delayed_job 2.0.4 gem.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions at: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/tree/v2.0, specifically the one regarding adding that snippet to your rakefile?

Comment: Yes. I have already added that code snippet into Rakefile. jobs:work rake task is also working fine.

Comment: Try adding 'include Delayed::Backend::Base' right inside your controllers.

Comment: I have tried with this. This time we are getting the same issue with the above include statement.